# Rewriting $\tau(p)\Delta(\tau)$ when $p$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, ramanujan-summation

$p$ is a prime, and $\tau$ is Ramanujan's tau function: 
$$p^{11}\Delta(p\tau)+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\Delta\bigg(\frac{\tau + k}{p}\bigg)=p^{11}\Delta(\tau)+\frac{p^{12}}{p}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\Delta(\tau) 
=p^{11}\Delta(\tau)+p^{12}\Delta(\tau)=p^{11}\Delta(\tau)(1+p)$$
I am unclear how the latest expression is equivalent to $\tau(p)\Delta(\tau)$, where $\Delta $ is the modular discriminant.

Comment: There is something very fishy about this calculation: $\tau$ seems to be used both for a variable and for a function, and the first "equality" is just nonsense -- why should $\Delta(p\tau)$ be equal to $\Delta(\tau)$?

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the fact that $\Delta$ is an eigenvector for the Hecke operators acting on $M_{12}$. A classical calculation of the effect of Hecke operators at the level of $q$-expansions shows that the Hecke eigenvalues of an eigenform are precisely its Fourier coefficients (more precisely, the $n$-th Hecke eigenvalue is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient). The expression you have written down is $T_p\Delta$, and therefore this equals $\tau(p)\Delta$.

Comment: What do you mean by $q$-expansion?

Comment: @cap It's just another name for the Fourier expansion. $q=\exp(2\pi i \tau)$

Comment: @BrunoJoyal can you give a reference to the calculation you are referring to?

Comment: @TheSubstitute: You should find it in Serre's *Course in arithmetic*, or in Diamond & Shurman's *Introduction to modular forms*, among others